# Which conversions and formatting options are supported in EF and SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

Imagine the following code:

```
var query = _data.UnitLogs.Select(c => new Unit
                  {
                      IdText = string.Format("ID:{0}",c.Id),
                      UserName = c.UserName
                  });
```

It will lead to the following exception if it's targetted to a SQL database:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Although this is perfectly clear, I experience this quite often.

So, the question:

*Is there any documentation available where the `Entity Framework` translatable expressions for SQL are documented?*

It would defenitly help me out with some sort and filter queries which I do in memory at the moment.

*update*

The question is not about adding `ToList()` before the selection, I am just looking for a list of acceptable translatable functions which can also be used in `OrderBy` and `Where` directly against the database.

Other example:

```
var query = _data.UnitLogs
                  .OrderBy(c => string.Format("{0:MM}", c.EntryDate)
                  .Select(c => new Unit
                  {
                      IdText = c.Id,
                      UserName = c.UserName
                  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `ToList()` prior to selection. Then you'll perform your operations with enumerated collection, not the IQueryable that tries to pass your expression via provider to database when enumerating it's results

```
var query = _data.UnitLogs.ToList().Select(c => new Unit
              {
                  IdText = string.Format("ID:{0}",c.Id),
                  UserName = c.UserName
              });
```

For the information you are asking, please have a look at MSDN here:

[CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx)

[Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the `ToList()` method and why it works. I just want a list with functions that can be executed against the database. (I must say, it would be better if my example was about sorting.) I think your msdn article will help.

Comment: Added the information about LINQ methods supported by Linq2Entities

Comment: for your updated question, you may use `.OrderBy(c => c.EntryDate.Month)` to order by months.

Comment: Thanks!, but the examples are just hypothetical :)